# How do you get CruiseControl to work with SVN?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol

I don't see any clear documentation on this....

1) Is the plugin installed already?

2) If not, where can it actually be found, how is it installed?

3) How can this be configured to handle authentication with SASL?

Is there anywhere on the internets that this has actually been shown in some kind of tutorial? The google results on this are dismal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/Using+CruiseControl+with+Subversion) is the documentation I use. Be warned though, the server is frequently down.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I just got mine to work:

I used the method in this link:

http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Subversion%20Source%20Control%20Block.html

you just need to have a good updated svn.exe that you can reference. this should be able to check for modifications from the repository and update working copy.

hope this helps someone out there!